# Error while creating scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I was trying to create a scratch org following the trailhead

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx/create-and-test-our-scratch-org?trail_id=sfdx_get_started

I'm stuck in the following section ***Create and Test Our Scratch Org*** -  **Step 2**

while executing the following command getting the following error.

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a dreamhouse-org
```

**ERROR running force:org:create:  Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.**

Steps Executed

1. Created Project in VSCode
2. Authorized an Org
3. Executed Trailhead steps as mentioned in the [link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx/set-up-the-project-on-your-local-machine?trail_id=sfdx_get_started)

Comment: Did you enable DevHub in your org?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm

I would repeat the steps in the answer here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MVBsQAO

Comment: Yes i have enabled

Comment: Have you tried passing the -u parameter with your dev hub's alias?

Comment: the CLI has had a bunch of updates over the past few days, are you running the latest CLI? Might be worth running `sfdx update` and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: in my case it was solved by adding missing -v DevHub (no default dev hub was set)

Answer (score 10):

You have to login first.

`sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub`

(This is in the [prior step](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx/set-up-your-salesforce-dx-environment?trail_id=sfdx_get_started), you can't work on them separately.)

Answer (score 5):

Authorize your Dev Hub on the same folder directory where you will create your scratch org.

```
\VSCodeQuickstart\my_sfdx_project\dreamhouse-sfdx$ sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub

\VSCodeQuickstart\my_sfdx_project\dreamhouse-sfdx$ sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a dreamhouse-org
```

Comment: That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

When working on multiple projects I am of the opinion it is a bad idea to have a default devhub org set; only a matter of time when a command gets executed against the wrong org :).

I don't have a default org set and explicitly specify it with `--targetdevhubusername=` when needed:

```
$ sfdx force:auth:web:login -a sf3
$ sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a dreamhouse-org --targetdevhubusername=sf3
```

Comment: BEST ANSWER FOR ME!!! It's super important to note that in the real world where you work with multiple projects at a time it's a terrible idea to set a default org. Thanks for this valuable additional information!!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. To resolve it, do the following step :

1. Re auth your org in ebikes-lwc folder(or your named folder) via following

   ```
   sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a ebikeslwcOrgAlias
   ```
2. Now try to create scratch org :

   ```
   sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ebikes
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but here is my finding who needs it.
Need to provide

```
--edition=developer|enterprise|group|professional|partner-developer|partner-enterprise|partner-group|partner-professional
```

Like this

```
    sf org create scratch --definition-file config/project-scratch-def.json --alias MyScratchOrg --set-default --edition=developer
```

Comment: Note that the reported error message was "Must pass a username..." Do you want to state that you get this error message by not providing the `edition` parameter in the prescribed way?! This is not even a required parameter - see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm).